# Neck showing during prayer

Tags: salat, awrah

Asalamualaykum

After I finished prayer I realised my neck was showing. Maybe it wasn’t for the whole prayer or maybe it was but what do you do if you realised your neck was showing **after** prayer? Also does it depend if a lot was showing or a bit ?